# How to show that $\varphi : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto (at-b^2t^2)(at-2b^2t^2)$ has a strict local minimum at $t=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> How to show that $\varphi : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto
> (at-b^2t^2)(at-2b^2t^2)$ has a strict local minimum at $t=0$

I found that $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2a^2>0$. But is that enough to conclude that at $t=0$, we have a *strict* local minimum?

Comment: yes, because the proof of the second derivative test actually shows it is a strict local minimum rather than weak local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

"Strict local minimum at $t=0$" means that there is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ such that $\phi(0)<\phi(t)$ for all $t$ with $0<|t|<\epsilon$.
Write $\phi$ in the form
$$\phi(t)=t^2(a-b^2 t)(a-2b^2 t)\ .$$
If $a\ne0$ then $\phi(0)=0$, and $\phi(t)>0$ for all sufficiently small $|t|>0$. Therefore $\phi$ has a strict local minimum at $t=0$.

If $a=0$ then $\phi(t)=2b^4 t^4$ has a strict local minimum at $t=0$, unless $b=0$.

If $a=b=0$ then $\phi(t)\equiv0$, so there is no strict local minimum of $\phi$ at $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second derivative being positive means that the gradient changes from negative to positive precisely as you require.

To see this intuitively, first consider a function which is zero at a point where its gradient is positive. Then to the left of that point the function is negative and to the right of that point the function is positive. Now apply this result to the function $f'(t)$ and we get the result stated in the opening lines of this answer.

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate?

Comment: Could you say what definition of strict local minimum you are using?